How do I make the pen on my tablet have relative positioning but also pen pressure?
I'm trying to use a Ugee M708 on clip art studio and the pen pressure only works when I have it set to Windows Ink Mode and not mouse mode. However Windows Ink Mode makes the cursor jump around rather than move relative to where it's placed.
Is there away I can fix on those problems?

Well, mouse mode isn't going to convey pressure, so that's expected. Input jumping around is usually an issue with the quality of the pen and digitizer tablet. Have you contacted ugee support regarding this? Have you checked for and installed any driver or firmware updates? Can you perhaps explain better or more clearly what you mean by "makes the cursor jump around"? Is this perhaps just a case of it behaving in a way you don't expect rather than it behaving in an actually wrong/broken manner?

so it seems to move relative to the tablet rather than relative to were the mouse is on the screen. So normally if you have a mouse near the top right pick up the physical one and move it bottom left the mouse on screen stays up in the top right. however with this, it would make it jump to the bottom left rather than stay in the top right. I think it's intentional I just want to change the setting bc I had this same tablet on my old pc and it worked like a mouse but with pen pressure. it's only since changing to the new pc I can't get the settings working how i liked them.

the tablet probably uses absolute positioning ... ie. top left corner of the tablet corresponds to the top left corner of the screen,  etc.

the title of your post does not match the description in the post ... please fix it

is there away to change it from absolute positioning to something else?

That will depend on the software settings available.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
